# Updating database to Migration Configuration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have pulled down a Visual Studio 2015 project created my another developer. Within the Migrations folder are several Migration Configuration files ...

- 201601081315335_AddedPersonEntities.cs
- 201601091532275_AddedDepartmentEntities.cs
- 201601101145137_AddedPayrollEntities.cs

I would like to update my database to the point of one of these Migration Configurations. However when I try this command ...

```
Update-Database -Verbose -StartupProjectName MyApp.Api -ProjectName MyApp.Data -ConfigurationTypeName 201601091532275_AddedDepartmentEntities.cs
```

I get the following error ...

`The migrations configuration type '201601091532275_AddedDepartmentEntities' was not be found in the assembly 'MyApp.Data'.`

I was expecting it would bring my database up to the same schema at the point that `201601091532275_AddedDepartmentEntities` was created. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to visual studio, select your `MyApp.Data` and check the "Show All Files".

[image: Show all files image]

Inside the migrations folder, see if there aren't migrations "outside" the project. If there is, then add them to the project with Right-Click > Include in project.

Do you use TFS?

It happens when you add something (File/Folder) inside a project in your solution and check-in your solution, and your colleague doesn't do correctly the merge on the .csproj file (Which contains all the information about the files and folders inside the project).

**WAIT**

Ok i think this isn't the problem.

You are specifying `-ConfigurationTypeName:` don't you want `-target:` instead?

- `-ConfigurationTypeName` Is used to define the configuration class (Normally contains the seed method).
- `-target` Specifies to where you want to update your database (From the current migration to that specific one, forward or backwards it works anyway).

And, do you insert the models inside `MyApp.Data` or `MyApp.Models`?